# Class App\Http\Controllers\homeController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

i'm using laravel 5 , in rutes.php i have this code :

```
Route::get('about',"homeController@about");
```

and in App\Http\Controllers\ i have file homeController.php that contains :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as BaseController;

class homeController extends BaseController{
public function about(){
    return view::make('about');
}
}
```

but it throws this error : Class App\Http\Controllers\homeController does not exist .
how can i fix it ?

here is structure of the project and controllers :
[image]

Comment: How about changing namespace App\Http\Controllers\homeController; as namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: @vural it does  not work

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HomeController`?

Comment: As i added the `controller` to the project manually, i think i should run `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 9):

First, check if you write the name of the controller correctly.
If it is, there are 3 methods:

1. `Route::get('/about', 'App\Http\Controllers\homeController@about');`
   Write all the paths where your controller there is.
2. `Route::get('/about', [HomeController::class, 'about');`
3. - Go to file RouteServiceProvider.php in Providers folder
   - Search for ***`//protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';`***
     ( You will find it in comment)
   - Remove `//` of comment and save.
     with this method, you will able to use the name of the controller directly without
     writing all the paths.

Comment: Using the second method inside an IDE would help the thread owner to see that the controller class has to be written starting with an uppercase letter as you've pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

Change all

```
homeController
```

To

```
HomeController
```

Answer (score 3):

change your routing like below:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/about',  [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

for more info look at this page:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Comment: Thanks, it work for me. 
I've same case but I forgot to place use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController; on my codes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For **HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function welcome()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

For **web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'welcome']);
```

Its work for me

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as BaseController;

class homeController extends BaseController{
  public function about(){
    return view::make('about');
  }
}
```

Comment: Try running command from your laravel project directory, `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: this command cleared the cache , but it did not solve the error

Comment: @ako Can you run `php artisan view:clear`, `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as BaseController;

class homeController extends BaseController{
  public function about(){
    return view::make('about');
  }
}
```

Should works perfectly. Are you sure that name of file is `homeController.php` ?

Comment: but in your screenshot 
`here is structure of the project and controllers :`
The name of file starts from capital letter

Comment: Change `Route::get('about',"HomeController@about");` to `Route::get('about',"homeController@about");` and try

Comment: If you want to mess up project structure, go ahead. If you have a very good reason to do so, well, go ahead. But if not, classes should start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue with the Home controller, in my case I saw the route was configured as following:

```
Route::get('/home',"homeController@index");
```

when I changed the above code to the following then it worked.

```
Route::get('/home',"App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@about");
```

In your case first, check the spelling first, whether it should be HomeController or homeController.

You can change your route code to the following

so you can try to change the following code

```
Route::get('about',"HomeController@about");
```

to

```
Route::get('about', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@about');
```

or

```
Route::get('/about', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@about');
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

**It can happen because of these two causes:**

1. Typo Error
2. Laravel Cache

**1) Type Error**
For this check, please check your HomeController file name and the class name in that file. Both should be same with case sensitivity.

> **HomeController**.php
>
> class **HomeController** extends

**2) Laravel Cache**
Laravel stores file caches with previous configurations. To refresh the cache, do this commands in the command window and then try again

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Hope it solved!.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is right because you are not giving right path to the action in the routes. Either you update core files for path or provide manually in the route. e.g
you have

```
Route::get('about',"homeController@about");
```

try this route

```
Route::get('/about', [App\Http\Controllers\homeController::class,'about']);
```

or you can type route as

```
Route::get('/about', 'App\Http\Controllers\homeController@about');
```

furthermore you can check if you have right code in the controller function.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying Laravel 7.x and before routing schema. Refer to 8.x documentation.

New syntaxis using as `[HomeController::class, 'index']` or you need to add namespace before `Controller` name like `App\Http\Controllers\HomeController`.

Answer (score 0):

Update the path to your route by adding .

```
Route::get('/home', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Answer (score -1):

Please update your route

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/about', [HomeController::class, 'about']);