# Class does not exist when up project to hosting

Tags: php, laravel

In localhost it runs ok, but when code is deployed to hosting there occurs an error in `router/web.php`. Code :

```
Route::get('about',"HomeController@index");
```

and in `App\Http\Controllers\` I have file `HomeController.php` that contains:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use App\TheLoai;
use App\LoaiTin;
use App\TinTuc;
use App\User;
use App\Slide;
use DB;

class HomeConTroller extends Controller
{
    //...
```

But it throws this error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist

How can I fix it?

Comment: Change `Route::get('about',"homeController@index"); ` to `Route::get('about',"HomeConTroller@index"); `

Comment: sr i write wrong, in code me it is: Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
; i write status in stack erro .... i copy tut so don't edit full ^^

Comment: In server operation system is linux or windows??

Comment: i use windown 7

Comment: Are you try my answer??

Comment: it don't work, in tut i write wrong, in me code it is HomeController, i copy in tut https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994417/class-app-http-controllers-homecontroller-does-not-exist because i don't dnow write tut in stack overflow ^^!

Comment: You must be change `HomeController` to `HomeConTroller`

Comment: yes, in web.php , name folder controller , class in controller, all is HomeController but it don't work

Comment: Can you show all parts??

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: class HomeConTroller extends Controller

Comment: Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Comment: HomeConTroller.php

Comment: That case change in web to `HomeConTroller`

Comment: then in console `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: in localhost it work, i test in hosting it erro, It’s the first time i up code to hosting

Comment: In Linux it is all paths is case -sensitive

Comment: @@ name file HomeController not HomeConTroller, in folder i up to hos it is HomeController, up to hos it to HomeConTroller. Thank you vr much ^^!, sr i don't know englíh so don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HomeConTroller  - should be HomeController - only C is capital

Comment: but it don't run, in localhost, i use class HomeConTroller extends Controller it run, i edit to HomeController but remain so erro Class App\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Change the controller's name from `HomeConTroller` to:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

Then run this to terminal:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Comment: i edited HomeConTroller to HomeController but it remain so erro